# Varchar to Numeric Conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have loaded the excel data into a table using SSIS.

Table Structure :

```
Monthly_Budget

SEQUENCE            INT IDENTITY,
TRANSACTION_DATE    VARCHAR(100),
TRANSACTION_REMARKS VARCHAR(1000),
WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT    VARCHAR(100),
DEPOSIT_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100),
BALANCE_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100)
```

Values in WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT Column:

```
7,987.00
1,500.00
7,000.00
50.00
NULL
253.00
4,700.00
2,000.00
148.00
2,000.00
64.00
1,081.00
2,000.00
NULL
NULL
7,000.00
```

Now, I am trying to run a query to get the summation of values under WITHDRWAL_AMOUNT but I am getting an error :

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

My Query :

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT)),0) AS NUMERIC(6,2))) AS NUM FROM MONTHLY_BUDGET
```

Comment: your problem stems from the poor database design: all those fields should NOT be varchar. Use the appropriate datatypes ffs!

Comment: I am using these fields as varchar so that I can properly load the data from excel to table (Data Conversion , data_type (DT_STR)).I also tried to use DT_NUMERIC after changing the table structure but it was not working.

Comment: Use appropriate datatypes. Period.

Comment: It's **much** easier to adjust the data in excel or with SSIS before import and use proper data types in the sql server table. Trust me on this. SSIS will allow you to choose better data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting them like this:

```
select SUM(CAST(ltrim(rtrim(replace(WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT, ',', ''))) as numeric(6, 2)) )
```

It is much, much preferable to store the values in the proper types that you want.  I can, however, understand putting external data into a staging table and then using logic such as the above to load the data into the final table.